# Why does HoloLens provide Hold gestures that are not used during the project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

In the process of doing the project, we saw that both the InputDown and InputUp methods had normal printing, but why did the Hold method not print all of them?[The following figure is part of the code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni2TA.png)

Comment: Please do not provide code as an image. Stack Overflow [supports code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll be careful.